# Quartz.Net - how to return a list of next fire times in 2.0

Tags: quartz.net, quartz.net-2.0

In version 1 we have computeFireTimes which will returns a list of Dates that are the next fire times of a Trigger

Is there a way to do the same thing in version 2

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use **GetNextFireTimeUtc** and **GetFireTimeAfter** ,

eg

```
    var dt = trigger.GetNextFireTimeUtc();

    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        if (dt == null)
             break;

        Console.WriteLine(dt.Value.ToLocalTime());

        dt = trigger.GetFireTimeAfter(dt);
    }
```

Comment: If I use calendar to exclude dates, those dates still show up in the for loop. Any idea how to get a list without those?

Answer (score 2):

Another option:

```
var times = TriggerUtils.ComputeFireTimes(trigger as IOperableTrigger, null, 10); 
foreach (var time in times) Debug.WriteLine(time.ToLocalTime());
```

This will return the next 10 fire times.